# How to call class decorator function without new keyword?

Tags: typescript

Can i call the class decorator function without using `new` keyword?

Example:

```
@doSomeThing
class Foo
{
   // class body...
}
```

I want to call `doSomeThing` function without using `new Foo();`

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found that the answer is no, i can't call class decorator without calling the class itself.